# How can I disable my Thinkpad T60's sound when the battery connection is changed?

Tags: audio, battery, thinkpad

I find all sounds my computer makes a bother. I have managed to turn off almost everything, but the "change state" between "on battery" and "on power" still remains.

How can I turn it off?

Thanks.

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: XP Pro >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Lenovo Power Manager utility installed, go into 'Global Power Settings' and uncheck 'Beep when power state changes'.  (This is on my T60p, Win7 32-bit with Power Manager 3.05)

Answer (score 2):

I have a T41, but on that computer, you can switch the sound on / off in the BIOS setup.

Comment: +1 for OS-independent answer. On a T60p it is in config->alarms.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you're referring to a system beep or a sound from the sound card. Either way, both can be disabled in device manager.

- Start -> Run -> `devmgmt.msc` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- View -> Show hidden Devices.
- Non-Plug and Play Drivers -> Beep -> Disable.

For your sound card:

- In the same device manager window, go to **Sound, video and game controllers**
- Right click your audio device and hit **disable**

reboot.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried the Non-Plug and play and that didn't do it.
As I am not very secure with changing my computer, I am hesitant to try the other. There are a number of devices and I don't want to turn off something I may need. I assume that it will be either the legacy audio drivers or the Audio Codecs. Can you tell me if I will need these in the future? My concern is that I will fix my immediate problem and not find a problem this causes until I can't remember how to do change it back.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an **IBM ThinkPad R50 running Windows XP Professional**. This is how I resolved it, after being inspired and informed by the preceding posts! Thanks to the previous contributors!

Click **"Start" > "Access IBM" > "ThinkPad Configuration."**

The "ThinkPad Configuration" dialog appears.

Click **"Power Management"** on the right-hand side of the dialog.

The **Power Options** dialog appears. Click **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wphVj.png)** to see the Power Options dialog.

On the **"Power Options" dialog**,  go to the **"Beeps/Alarms" tab**.

Set **"Power control beep" to "Disable."**

Click **"Apply."**

Close the dialogs.

The change should be immediate.
Enjoy a more silent ThinkPad experience!